# Opengl-es Android and TouchEvents

Tags: android, opengl-es, touch

Right now, I am trying to create a simple app where a square follows where your finger touches as you move it along the screen. I would like to do this using opengl-es. I am fairly new to it and right now I am stuck on mapping the window coordinates reported by the touch event to the cartesian plane coordinate system that the opengl-es has. Right now, to get the x and y translation, I am using:

```
final int x = (e.getX()-(getWidth()/2))/(getWidth()/2) * SOME_SCALING_FACTOR;
final int y = ((getHeight()/2)-e.getY())/(getHeight()/2) * SOME_SCALING_FACTOR;
```

The logic behind this is that I think the cartesian plane is centered around the screen so I am trying to re-map my touch event coordinates in that way. However, my results are very inaccurate. 
Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: Can you add how your projection (camera) is set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a SOME_SCALING_FACTOR there. It's better to configure OpenGL for it.

You may use code below to configure camera, then do your drawing.

```
gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, WINDOWx, 0, WINDOWy);
gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

The lower left point of screen will be origin, upper left is (0,WINDOWy) etc..

Comment: This is the solution I went for already. I think it's supposed to be GLU.gluOrtho2D (gl, 0, WINDOWx, WINDOWy, 0); Thanks though ! :P

Comment: Yes, `GLU.gluOrtho2D (gl, 0, WINDOWx, WINDOWy, 0);` is the correct one :)